# How to automate vocabulary game

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="t_monit">
          <div class="t_txt_wrap">
              <div id="munArea">
  <div class="t_lev_tit" id="levans" style="padding-top:40px;" rel="4" idx="31|2" ansidx="31|2" a4="31|2">identify</div>
  <ul class="t_lev_list">
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="ansChk" a1="1" a2="4" a3="12103|1" a5="2">반대하다</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="ansChk" a1="2" a2="4" a3="26294|1" a5="2">소중히 여기다</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="ansChk" a1="3" a2="4" a3="9778|1" a5="2">흉내 내다</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="ansChk" a1="4" a2="4" a3="31|2" a5="2">동일시하다</a></li>
    </ul></div>
              <div class="mun_mask" style="background-color: transparent; display: none;"><center><img src="/html/images/test_x.png" class="imgox" style="display:none; padding-top:40px;" id="img_x"><img src="/html/images/test_o.png" class="imgox" style="display:none; padding-top:40px;" id="img_o"></center></div>
              <!-- 페이저 : S -->
              <div class="t_pager"><span id="noarea">2</span> / 30</div>
              <!-- 페이저 : E -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is HTML of vacabulary game. Click the right answer and go to next vocabulaty. Div munArea is the example and the answer is among the class "ansChk".  As you can see if the value of the "idx" or "ansidz" matches the value of the "a3". That is the answer. I tried to get the value of "idx" and "a3" but everytime only to give me something like selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(session="bd0c472720ca6f980f201f6969698a6b", element="108c16c9-66f8-4998-a60b-844c957e7aa5").

```
e2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('munArea > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a')
```

I spent few hour to solve this but I don't know how to get the value but i only to get the text inside the page.
 divs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ansChk') gave me selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(session="bd0c472720ca6f980f201f6969698a6b", element="108c16c9-66f8-4998-a60b-844c957e7aa5"). 
                                                                                                       The approximate code i want:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pprint import pprint
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import pyautogui 
import time

while True:
        answer = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#levans')
        lists = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ansChk')
        print(lists) #see what's going on 
        print(answer)
        time.sleep(4)
        print('-------------------')
        if answer.get_attribute('idx') == lists.get_attribut('a3'):
            pyautogui.click(lists)
```

print(lists) and print(answer)

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c5de78335a75eddcc9ebfdcb2c9683ac", element="a366bcc2-7a21-417d-af57-7184b81bc625")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c5de78335a75eddcc9ebfdcb2c9683ac", element="33a3e05b-3ebc-4518-b7ac-04a509e38fe3")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c5de78335a75eddcc9ebfdcb2c9683ac", element="d3522d7d-70ba-4298-ba28-b80876ddd0f9")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c5de78335a75eddcc9ebfdcb2c9683ac", element="42804b14-47bb-4307-ae8f-f8c0186fd2bc")>]
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c5de78335a75eddcc9ebfdcb2c9683ac", element="2d2010a1-6e1b-4605-8b1d-2c8b7c106166")>
```

I don't think I got right value. 
I want to give you the page Link but it is not F2P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List doesn't have `get_attribute()` method.You need to iterate the list and then use `get_attribute()` on each element to verify matching values.

**Code**:

```
while True:
        answer = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#levans')
        lists = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ansChk')
        for list in lists:
            if answer.get_attribute('idx') == list.get_attribute('a3'):
               pyautogui.click(list)
```

**Update**:

```
while True:
        answer = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#levans')
        lists = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ansChk')
        for list in lists:
            print(answer.get_attribute('idx'))
            print(list.get_attribute('a3'))
            if answer.get_attribute('idx') == list.get_attribute('a3'):
               pyautogui.click(list)
```

Comment: It doesn't work... Maybe  the way getting  answer = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#levans')  is wrong.

Comment: answer and lists printed something like selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.

Comment: @pi4q : It would be better if you share your url? I have just change the logic what you have done wrong?

Comment: @pi4q : Those are webelement.so you need to either print text or any attribute.Check updated one.

Comment: as i mentioned It is not F2P.  https://www.vocaending.co.kr/html/body/learn/testdan           I can just give you what you want.

Comment: My laptop is overheating so I'll run it later

Comment: 3739|1
3739|1
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "voca.py", line 67, in <module>
    pyautogui.click(list)
  File "Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 523, in click
    _mouseMoveDrag('move', x, y, 0, 0, duration, tween)
  File "Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1022, in _mouseMoveDrag
    x = int(x) if x is not None else startx
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'WebElement'

Comment: @pi4q : I don't know  how `pyautogui` works.You need to investigate that.I have just provided solution to your initial problem.why don't you use `list.click()` instead `pyautogui`?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
question= driver.find_element_by_id('levans').get_attribute("idx")
print (question.text)

element= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//munArea//ul//li//a")
  for items in element:   
     print (items.text)
     if(items.get_attribute("a3")==question):
        print("found")
     else:
        print("not found")
```

Comment: It gives  me :     print (question.text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'